# Does C has pass by reference?

Tags: c

I have this function here that my compiler is complaining. It keeps saying that is missing parenthesis which is not. If I remove the ampersand then the compiler stops complaining.
So my question is. Does C support ampersand? Should I use a pointer instead? so change int &cnt to int *cnt?

```
int counter (int in, int &cnt, int &en)
{
    static int in_old = 0;

    if (in_old == 0)
        if (in > 10)
            cnt = cnt + 1;
    if (cnt > 1)
        en = 1;

    in_old = in;
    // write counter code here

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: C is exclusively pass by value, you have to use a pointer to simulate pass by reference.

Comment: ...and then use `*cnt = *cnt + 1;` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not have references.
This code must come from C++!

Note however, that C does use the ampersand operator to obtain the address of a variable.

So if you change your function to accept pointers, you could do something like this:

```
int counter (int in, int *cnt, int *en);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int the_cnt = 1;
    int the_en = 2;
    int in = 3;

    int res = counter(in, &cnt, &en);

    ...
}
```

You will also have to dereference the pointers in the function:

```
int counter (int in, int *cnt, int *en)
{
    static int in_old = 0;

    if (in_old == 0)
        if (in > 10)
            *cnt = *cnt + 1;
    if (*cnt > 1)
        *en = 1;

    in_old = in;
    // write counter code here

    return 0;

}
```